# Add space between \hline and superscript without affecting any other spacing

Tags: spacing, superscripts

I want to add space between `\hline` and `A^T` without affecting any other spacing.

[image]

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
$\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
$\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using `\midrule` from `booktabs` package instead, it also include a macro to add mode space above/below a line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add an invisible rule of an appropriate height (this is what `\strut` and `\mathstrut` do, but they are not tall enough in this case):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  \hline
  $\begin{array}{c}
    \vrule width 0pt height 2.2ex
    a\leftarrow A^Tb \\
    c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
  \hline
  $\begin{array}{c}
    \vrule width 0pt height 2.2ex
    a\leftarrow A^Tb \\
    c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand*\mymathstrut{\ifmmode\vrule width 0pt height 2.2ex\fi}`?

Comment: @1010011010 Certainly worth doing if it is to be used often, perhaps `\newcommand*{\mymathstrut}[1][2.2ex]{\ifmmode\vrule width 0pt height #1\fi}` would give more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cellspace` package, which defines `minimal` vertical spacings between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and between its bottom and the top of the below cell. If the spacing is greater than the minimum, it adds nothing. You just have to add the pre-specifier `S` in front of the column specifier. Example with a minimum of 2 pt above, 1pt below. I set the array left-aligned as I think it looks better:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math]{cellspace}%
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{ 2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Sl}
\hline
$\begin{array}{l}a ← A^Tb \\ c ← A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
$\begin{array}{l}a ← A^Tb \\ c ← A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]